# How far back in the storyline do I have to go to be able to save Eve on Tuchanka?

Tags: mass-effect-3

So I was playing the Tuchanka missions, but Eve died on me, and we can't have that, so I dug up some save editors and changed my ME2 plot choice so that I saved Maelon's cure. It's weird that she dies at all, since I can't imagine why I would've opted to destroy Maelon's cure in the first place since it's apparently a paragon choice to save it - could this be a glitch? I then tried to replay the *last* Tuchanka mission, but she still dies. All of my squadmates were loyal at the end of ME2, and all of them survived the suicide mission.

I'm an avid game-saver, so my question is: how far back in the storyline do I have to go for the Maelon's cure boolean to take effect and change the outcome, i.e. to save Eve and keep the Krogans in check?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Eve):

> **If the player chose to destroy Maelon's data** back in Mass Effect 2,
>   then at the very end of the genophage cure quest line on Tuchanka,
>   regardless of whether or not the player chose to allow Mordin or Wiks
>   to fix the sabotaged cure, **Eve will collapse and die** due to
>   complications coming from having the genophage cure being based on
>   incomplete data.

Additionally:

> Also, **if the quest to disarm the rearmed turian bomb** left over from
>   the Krogan Rebellions **is left uncompleted**, then the bomb detonates and
>   Shepard will receive a message from the Urdnot leader stating that **Eve
>   has died**.

Comment: Indeed, I did the missions in the recommended order: cerberus presence, survivors, bomb disarming and lastly curing the genophage. After having edited my coalesced data and checking with gibbed save editor, it now states I saved Maelon's data (for sure). I'm left wondering how far back in the storyline I have to revert for this to take effect? Restarting the genophage mission wasn't enough, so I'm going to try to replay the whole Krogan DMZ to see if that will allow me to keep her alive. I'll post back if noone beats me to it.

Comment: You would probably need to go back before you even rescue Eve, because there it states that you destroyed the data. So changing your game save after it probably did not change something in that conversation piece to make it where you saved the data to help mordin make the cure.

Comment: I went all the way back to my second visit to the citadel, before meeting the diplomats and saving Eve, before the rachni mission, the n7 missions and all the ones on Tuchanka. Quite some ways. Although my save editor claims I saved the data, everyone's acting the same and Mordin can't seem to figure out the cure. This isn't looking good. Either the activating point for saving Eve is before surkesh, or the game's glitched out on me. What would support that, is that this time when I talked to Liara (expecting to get warp skill) I didn't. It's not unlocked and it's not in the medbay. For shame.

Comment: Yea, she died on me again. I wonder what the chances are she would survive in a second play-through...

I thought I wouldn't, but I'm soldiering on despite that critical loss - wonder what the likelyhood is they'll actually make a ME4? Anything interesting being said about that? Guess they've got their hands full with the extended cut, eh? On that, and in conclusion, I suppse I'm in for a good helping of more disappointment at the end of all this. Well, I'll wait for the extended cut if/before I go for my second play-through, which - let's face it - is still very likely to happen...

Answer (score 0):

Since you used a save editor it may not actually work that way. Your best bet is to go back and play ME2 and save the cure. However if the save editor works you should edit your old ME2 save to say that you kept the cure and import that save into ME3. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So you're saying the results of my actions are written in stone from the very beginning of the game and I have to start a new game in order for the imported choices to take effect and change stuff? It would seem likely, but it said I was supposed to be able to rewrite my choices on the fly in the support-section of the ME3 coalesced-editor. This is clearly not the case.

Replaying from the second one might be a good choice, since I'd much like to go back and save the cure to restore hope for the krogans and try out the Jack and Tali sandwich. Thanks again for the input

Comment: @odist - Very little is known about the import process beyond the obvious stuff ( reading the flags in the import save for instance ).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a quick solution, there is another way you can do this, using a sort of 'hack' to modify the game files directly. In *Gibbed's Editor*, bool value 1456 must be set as true - this tells the game that you've played Mass Effect 2.